# how can I update a meter inside a function? (appJar)

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

Python 2.7 user here.

Whenever I call a function, the guy "freezes", until the function is done. This however poses a problem, as I'd like a meter I have in the main window to keep updating as the function goes. How do I do that? I've tried using `.registerEvent(function)`, but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I've just messed up.

Anyways, the function I'm calling is from an imported module.

Comment: The first thing you need is the result of a measurement to pass to `setMeter`. How do you expect to measure the progress of the function? With most functions you can't do that.

Comment: @Goyo Okay,  I wasn't clear: at specific points on my function, I want it to grow to a specific percentage; of course I used `setMeter`, but the GUI doesn't update until the function is done, that's the problem. I hope I've cleared things up a bit

Comment: If it is you writing the function all you need is calling `setMeter` at those specific points. If it's not working and you need help with debugging we need a [mcve] to debug.

Comment: @Goyo Thank you, I solved my problem by writing an example; I'm sorry, I'm still a novice. Thanks again!